# I need to create a new relationship between two models(rails) and then change an attribute of the relationship model via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have a formula called "checked" which checks whether a user answer is true or false (this needs to be in javascript). Upon it being true, In rails I need to create a new relationship between the user and the step, which has an attribute of "state".  Once created, I need to change that state to "finished" from "pending".  After the user clicks the next button, I need to move to the next step.   I am very confused how to do this given that I don't think I can just put ruby into my javascript.

question.html.erb

```
<script>
   var checked = // this is a function that returns true or false based on whether user answer is correct - assume this works
       if(checked)
        {

            //display correct-answer dialogue
            $('#modal-simple-success').modal('show')  <<< this works fine

            //create a relationship between User and Step (UserStep Model) 
            <%= current_user.user_steps.build(step_id: @step.id)} %> << need help here considering cant have ruby in javascript

            //after building the relationship between the two models, change state from pending to finished
            <%= @user_steps.state.finish! %> <<need help here


            //move to next step
            $('#next-button').on('click', move to next step??? <<need help here 

        }
        else
        {
            //display wrong-answer dialogue
            $('#modal-simple-failure').modal('show')


        }
</script>
```

Here is my controller for steps:

```
class StepsController < ApplicationController   

    def show
        @course = Course.find(params[:course_id])
        @level = Level.find(params[:level_id])
        @step = Step.find(params[:id])
        @user_step = current_user.user_steps.find(params[:id])
    end

end
```

I thought about changing my submit button from this:

```
<div class="checkAnswer" data-toggle="modal">
  <%= link_to_function "check answer", 'execute();', class: "btn btn-success"%>
</div>
```

to this:

```
   <div class="checkAnswer" data-toggle="modal">
    <%= form_for(current_user.user_steps.build(step_id: @step.id), remote: true) do |f| %>
     <div><%= f.hidden_field :step_id %></div>
     <%= f.submit "check answer", class: "btn btn-success"%>
    <% end %>
   </div>
```

But would still need to initiate the execute(); function and not sure how to change the state still.

Any help on the right way to go about this would be appreciated.

Comment: It is very difficult to tell what `checked` does and why it needs to be in JavaScript

Comment: It draws from an embedded api that is in javascript (microsoft excel sheet).  So it checks a value entered into this excel API against a value from the database.  I have that working properly, meaning it properly passes a true or false to the function.  However, I need help with the rest of the behavior.  Net net: it passes true or false to the if/else condition and it needs to be in javascript

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, I would put all that ruby code inside an AJAX call. I recommend you put it in the Step controller since you have access to `current_user` in any controller. Try:

```
<%= link_to 'check answer',
  step_next_path(@step),
  remote: true,
  method: post %>
```

And set a route, say:

```
resources :steps do
  post 'next', to: 'steps#next'
end
```